# Why some existing Facebook test user is logged off and can no longer log in while not being deleted?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, selenium, facebook-test-users

I'm doing some kind of load testing with [Facebook Test Java API](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-test-java-api/) for some app using fb authorization.

Since I'm doing selenium test in parallel, i'm able to see some effect:

1. I'm creating some test user
2. I get it's loginURL
3. I'm authorizing in selenium-driven browser with this loginURL
4. I'm creating many other users, each of them doing some stuff and becoming friend to the user from point 1, that is seen in selenium-driven browser.
5. At some moment I see this user logged off from facebook in browser. The exact moment is not clear, since the other test users are created and made friend with the target user in parallel threads, but it looks like this happens when i create 500 users.
6. When I try to log in again with loginURL obtained at step 2 it is still impossible. The fb redirects me to the login page.
7. It is possible to create much more than 500 users (at least 2000) with the api before the api will return the error, but the logging off is observed much before the  reaching this limit.

The question is what is the limit of test facebook users supported with no problems?

And also, I've noticed that at beginning of the test test user access tokens worked okay, but by the end of the test all they were invalid and graph api didn't allowed to upload photos using that tokens.

Comment: They have secured just because hackers like you should not run and play around with bots in their website. You should probably contact facebook admins :)

Comment: sure? I supposed the test users are intended for running and playing around, to test that my app is capable to work with 100, 500, 1000, 2000-friends user. And the load testing in fact doesn't load the fb itself, but some system on my side.

Comment: I do not see a limit as such, but you could check the limit by creating test users and stop the count when you get `Error code: 2900 (Too many test accounts)` (based off https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/) Also from what i recollect when i used this, was the limit was 500, but that was 3 years back, things could have changed

Comment: the problem is that I still don't see 'too many test accounts' error, but some of already created accounts become to log off and no longer able to log in. that's strange.

Comment: So are you guessing that there must be a limit for no. of simultaneous logins for your IP?

Comment: I guess it is not limited for specific IP (as for me, users should have possibility even to do the load testing with test users, if, for some reason it is needed and can't be done without fb login for instance). But it looks like there is a hidden bug there: some pool of test users is extended to 2000 and more, while the pool of test users you can be authorized simultaneously is still 500 as in the earliest  version of test users api. That makes me sad.